# Laravel on Ubuntu with Apache2 not working

Tags: laravel, apache2

i tried to configure laravel for apache2.

But if I open http://localhost/ it redirect me to http://localhost/login and there is nothing to display.

If I try http://localhost/index.php/login I get the view blade to login. But how can I remove the /index.php/

The Apache vHost config

[image: My vhost config]

And the "main" route

```
Route::get('/home', function() {
    return Redirect::to('login'); 
});

Route::group([], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');

    Route::get('galleries', 'GalleryController@getGalleries');
    Route::get('galleries/{GID}', 'GalleryController@getPicuteGallery');    

    Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index');
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

    Route::get('search', 'Search\SearchController@index');

    Route::get('calendar', 'CalendarController@index'); 

    Route::get('symposium', 'SymposiumController@index');

    Route::get('conference', 'ConferenceController@index');

    Route::get('publication', function() {
        return view('publication'); 
    });
});
```

The Auth routes are predefined by AdminLTE installer.

```
/**
 * Define the AdminLTETemplate routes.
 */
protected function defineRoutes()
{
    if (!$this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        $router = app('router');

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->getAppNamespace().'Http\Controllers'], function () {
            require __DIR__.'/../Http/routes.php';
        });
    }
}
```

And the AdminLTE Router

```
<?php
/*
 * Same configuration as Laravel 5.2:
 * See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate    /Auth/Console/stubs/make/routes.stub
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

**---UPDATE---**

I found out that the mod_rewrite wasnt enabled. Now the web site works fine.

But I need to add the 'middleware' => 'web' class

Comment: Can you show your web server config file (part with paths to Laravel directory) and `route.php` please?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I added the infos to my post

Answer (score 0):

Remove `['middleware' => 'web']` from you `routes.php`, because since Laravel 5.2.27 this middleware applies automatically to all your routes and if you're adding it manually, it may give you broken app.

UPDATE:

You have a function which redirects you to 'dashboard' (why?) and also the function is not closed. So try to remove these lines:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return Redirect::to('dashboard');
```

Comment: I removed it, but still the same problem.

Comment: I added the whole router.php and additional infos

Comment: Please read an update. Why are you tryiing to redirect to 'dashboard' when user is trying to load root page? Also, try to remove `web` middleware as I said, when you test things. And try to clear routes cahce: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Thanks for Anwser. The dashboard redirect is because of the "default" landing page is under construction. It is only a temp route.
Now I removed the middleware web from every router! But the problem is still the same